# General solution of second order differential equations that are not equal to 0.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

My question is "Compute the general solution of $y''+2y'+y= (t^{-1})(e^{-t})$."

So far, I know that my characteristic equation is $r^2+2r+1=0$ and therefore my repeated root is $r= -1$.

From that, I know that $y(t)=C_1e^{-t} + C_2te^{-t}$.
I don't know where to go from here to complete the question.

Any corrections or suggestions?

Comment: The usual answer is to use the Green's function or variation of parameters to get a particular solution to the problem. This particular problem might be a bit ugly because the $1/t$ will want to blow up at $t=0$ which means the Green's function at $t=0$, which is just $t e^{-t}$, does not help you.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**

The differential equation being $$y''+2 y'+y=\frac{e^{-t}}{t}$$ you could start using $$y=z e^{-t}\qquad y'= \left(z'-z\right)e^{-t}\qquad y''= \left(z''-2 z'+z\right)e^{-t}$$ This makes the differential equation to be $$ z''e^{-t}=\frac{e^{-t}}{t}$$ that is to say $$z''=\frac 1 t$$ which seems to be quite simple to integrate.

I am sure that you can take it from here.